# wxWidgets: Frame size is not changing in Image panel

Tags: c++, image, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I am using wxWidgets 'An Image Panel' code. Here I made only one change.
I want frame size should be equal to image size, My Image size is 762x463, but my frame size is different. frame SetSize function is not working.

```
wxImagePanel::wxImagePanel(wxFrame* parent, wxString file, wxBitmapType format) :
wxPanel(parent)
{
    image.LoadFile(file, format);
}

void wxImagePanel::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt)
{
    // depending on your system you may need to look at double-buffered dcs
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void wxImagePanel::paintNow()
{
    // depending on your system you may need to look at double-buffered dcs
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void wxImagePanel::render(wxDC&  dc)
{
    dc.DrawBitmap( image, 0, 0, false );
}

class MyApp: public wxApp
    {
        
        wxFrame *frame;
        wxImagePanel * drawPane;
    public:
        bool OnInit()
        {
            // make sure to call this first
            wxInitAllImageHandlers();
            
            wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
            wxBitmap image(wxT("properties.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
            frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("Hello wxDC"), wxPoint(50,50), wxSize(image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()));  // 762x463
            
            // then simply create like this
            drawPane = new wxImagePanel( frame, wxT("image.jpg"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);
            sizer->Add(drawPane, 1, wxEXPAND);
            
            frame->SetSizer(sizer);
            
            frame->Show();
            return true;
        } 
        
    };
```

Comment: @badaishabaz, What is `'An Image Panel' code`? Also, the screenshot of the running the program would help tremendously...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the frame sized to display the image, you need to make 2 changes:

1. In the constructor `wxImagePanel::wxImagePanel`, you need to add a line to set a minimum size for the image panel.

```
wxImagePanel::wxImagePanel(wxFrame* parent, wxString file, wxBitmapType format) :
wxPanel(parent)
{
    image.LoadFile(file, format);
    SetMinSize(image.GetSize());
...
```

An alternate, and possibly better, solution would be to override [wxWindow::DoGetBestClientSize](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#afe8447cb5975584ee3d4a03e3d02ee89) for your wxImagePanel class and have it return `image.GetSize();`.

Incidentally, in the code shown above, there is nothing that actually connects the paint handler to the paint event, so you probably also want to add a line like

```
Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &wxImagePanel::paintEvent, this);
```

to the constructor as well.

2. In the body of `MyApp::OnInit`, change the line

```
frame->SetSizer(sizer);
```

to

```
frame->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
```

Using the [SetSizerAndFit](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a29938af9828fd35da666536cdfb6b73c) method will tell the frame to resize itself to the smallest size necessary to display all of its contents.  Since in step 1 the minimum size of the image panel was set to the size of `image` and the image panel is the only content of the frame, the frame will be sized to fit the image.